# How to implement custom endpoints in a URL shortener slug

Tags: node.js, url, redirect, backend

Of all the URL shorteners I have tried, no one allows you to add `/` is a slug but Rebrandly. E.g: let's say `bit.ly/abc`, this works, but `bit.ly/abc/xyz`, this doesn't. But in Rebrandly, `rebrand.ly/abc/xyz` & `rebrand.ly/abc`, both work. I tried implementing it on my own, but since we have to use params (`:slug`), when I visit `domain.com/abc/xyz`, it says `cannot get domain.com/abc/xyz` even though, the slug is registered in the DB.

EDIT:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const ogDetails = await viewOg(req.params.id)

        if (ogDetails === undefined) res.redirect('/')
        else if (ogDetails) res.render('view', { og: ogDetails })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error, 'error')
    }
})
```

Here, if the `:id`, matches something like `abc`, it works as expected. But let's say it has something like `abc/xyz`, then I get `cannot get path /abc/xyz` even though the data is there.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you are building an URL shortener, you have an issue with your code but you're not showing us your code? It's hard to guess what your problem might be.

Comment: @Evert, it's not about the code. It's about implementing something like that. the basis of how any URL shortener works is using the params and using them to find and then redirecting it. But when `/` get's involved, it gets tricky.

Comment: Does it? I never have issues getting any part of the URI I'm interested in. Can you demonstrate in any way what you're having difficulty with. If not, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @Evert, I have made some edits to the question to get a better understanding.

Comment: If you want `/:id` to capture *everything* after the slash, you don't need the router at all. Just write a plain middleware. Routers are like fancy middlewares that only invoke the callback if the path matches, but you don't need that... you want to match every path.

Comment: I think I am not able to express myself properly, see the last statement. I want to get the `abc/xyz` as a whole.

Comment: `req.path` gives you the whole path.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Evert, using the `req.path` instead of `req.params` is the way to go. It will give you the entire path entered.